# IPV6 Cryptographically Generated Address implementation

Tags: cryptography, network, ipv6

I am looking to an Cryptographically Generated Address (CGA) implementation in Java or in C++.
Would be glad if someone can help.

Comment: Can you be clearer about what you're looking for?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_Generated_Address -- at the moment, there's an RFC that describes this, but I haven't heard of any implementations.

Comment: I voted to close. SS is not about programming.

Comment: Interesting concept... @Ams, it's not *not* about programming. I was doubtful, but now it seems to me to be on topic, he's looking for an implementation of a cryptographic protocol. That said, I dont think an answer will be forthcoming, as per @Jeff's comment...

Comment: @AviD, unfortunately, for me it seems that SS is becoming completely about everything that contains even some mention of security related item. I would agree it is on-topic if security weakness, or possibilities how to strengthen the solution were discussed.

Comment: I think I agree with Ams on this one. The query is 'how to implement' which is really a programming question

Comment: @Rory, usually in cryptography-related issues, we answer "how to implement" with: `"Don't."` As in, he should use standard implementations - and how to do *that* is very much ontopic, IMO...

Answer (score 3):

http://www.thc.org/thc-ipv6/   a whole suite if ipv6 utilities, but sendpees6 has great examples of how to do CGA against SEND.

Comment: Interesting.  Here is one example of a DoS attack capitalizing on the extra overhead of verifying the signatures: [Project 13x: IPv6 DoS with sendpees6 (10 pts.)](http://samsclass.info/ipv6/proj/proj-124-13x-sendpees6.html)

Comment: i was looking more for a tool ,which could generate  CGA address.

Comment: `cga_opt = thc_generate_cga(prefix, key, &cga);`  is how you generate it if you're using the thc toolkit.  Is that close enough?

Comment: @nealmcb, funny, that's exactly what I did for my thesis few years ago when thc's code wasn't nearly as functional ;)  The fun part about SeND is that the client gets to pick the strength of the key, so you can kill any SeND aware node by precreating a packet and then just replying it as fast as you can.  Depending on the speeds of the CPU's, I've been able to kill a node by playing <25 packets a second.